# Find the last index of a bracket without counting the inside brackets in Java

Tags: java

I'm making a calculator and I'm pretty new to Java. I want my calculator to be able to calculate cosinus, sinus and tangens which I'm struggling with.

My main problem is to only calculate f.ex. cosinus of a string that looks like this: "cos(10)+(30)". You can see my code below.

```
String formula = "cos(10)+(30)";

if (formula.contains("cos") 
{
     String afterCos = (formula.substring(formula.lastIndexOf("cos"), formula.length()));

    int countOpen = (afterCos.length())-(afterCos.replace("(", "").length());
    int countClosed = (afterCos.length())-(afterCos.replace(")", "").length());

    while (countOpen >= countClosed) 
    {
         if ((countOpen-countClosed) == 0) 
         {
            String inside = afterCos.substring(afterCos.indexOf("(")+1, afterCos.lastIndexOf(")"));
            System.out.println(inside);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

After this the string `inside` will be `10)+30`.
How can I get it to only focus on the bracket after the `10`? 
On a side note I also need it to be able to handle multiple brackets inside of the cos-brackets.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: Your approach is pretty basic. Consider looking into Regular Expressions using `Pattern`, `Matcher` and other classes that better suit your task. Unless you may have brackets inside brackets (recursion) because then RegEx is not suited for that.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you try to fix such problems, the best approach is to convert them to POSTFIX notation. Meaning, the operators will appear at the end, and should be applied on the operators right in front of them. The best part of this method is, you don't need any parenthesis. The operator precedence is built in.

Example:

```
Original Expression: (x + y)*(p/q + r)
POSTFIX notation: x y + p q / r + * (no need of parenthesis)
```

Here is the pseudo code to convert an expression into POSTFIX notation.

1. Maintain two `stack`s one for the operators (**operator** stack) and other for the operands (**operand** stack)
2. Repeat the following for each word of the expression

   - If the word is an operand, place it in the operand stack
   - If the word is operator,

     - If the operator stack is not empty, check the precedence of the operator on the top of the stack.

       - If the operator on the stack is of higher precedence, then pop the **operator** from the stack, and push it on the **operand** stack, the push the current operator into the **operator** stack.
       - If the operator on the stack is of lower precedence, then push the operator on the **operator** stack
     - If the operator is empty, push the operator onto the **operator** stack
3. If all operands are done, then pop all the operators from the **operator** stack and push them on to the **operand** stack

Now, once the expression is parsed, it is time to evaluate the expression. Use the following pseudo code to evaluate a POSTFIX expression:

1. Repeat until the stack has only one element left (this is the result)

   - Pop the top element from the **operand** stack.

     - If the element is **operator**, push it into the **operator** stack.
     - If the element is **operand**, check the top of the **operator** stack.

       - If it is a *Unary* operator, pop the **operator** stack and apply that operator on the operand, and push the result on the **operand** stack
       - If it is a *Binary* operator, pop the **operand** stack (second element)

         - If the second element is operator, then push the first operand and the operator onto the **operator** stack.
         - If the second element is operand, then pop **operator** stack, and apply the operation on the two operands, and push the result on the **operand** stack.
       - If it is an operand, pop the **operator** stack twice (to get the operand and the binary operator), and apply the binary operation on the two operands. And push the result into the **operand** stack.

The element left on the **operand** stack is the result of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

To seperate this string "cos(10)+(30)" as cos(10) and (30) you can use StringTokenizer with + as seperator to get the tokens.